# jQuery create an element and get height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I created a div in jquery whose width and height set automatically and I would like to assign the height value to line-height.

```
$('<div>')
    .css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': 0, 'right': 0, 'top': 0, 'bottom': 0,
        'line-height': $(this).height()
    });
```

But `$(this)` is the body element so the line-height is the height of body.

Someone has a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Until that element is inserted into the DOM, it has no height, so your assumptions are wrong. Also note that line-height is set with a number relative to the given font-size, unless a unit is supplied, such as px, em etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the callback function. `css` method will call the function, the returned value of the function is used for setting the property's value:

```
$collection.css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'left': 0, 'right': 0, 'top': 0, 'bottom': 0,
    'line-height': function() {
        return $(this).height() + "px";
    }
});
```

Note that as you haven't added the element to the document the `div` element's height is `0`, you should call the `css` method after appending the element.